# Prove that $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\,\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ decreases as $n$ increases.

Tags: inequality, induction, provability

Please help me to prove the following problem with inductive argument
$$\left(\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+\dots+\left(\frac{n+1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}<\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n+\dots+\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^n \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\,.$$

I think we can use the following solution to prove the main problem:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac1n $$
$$(\frac1{n+1})^{n+1}<(\frac1n )^n$$

Thanks...

Comment: I tried to edit your post to make it more readable.  Please check to make sure that I didn't mess anything up.

Comment: It looks like there might be better avenues to prove this than with induction.  Is induction required?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Yes induction is not best answer but its required.

Comment: Is it then allowed to prove first by induction the equality $$\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{n\text{ times}}=n\ ,$$ then use this result and a quick way to finish?

Comment: I observe that the approximation $$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\,\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\approx \frac{\text{e}}{\text{e}-1}\,\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=:T_n$$ is extremely good, and at least the inequality $$T_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n+1}}<T_n^{\frac1n}$$ holds for every $n\geq3$.

Comment: Oooppss, I made a computational error.  In the comment above, $T_n$ should be replaced by $$T_n:=\frac{\text{e}}{\text{e}-1} \left(1-\frac{\text{e}+1}{2(\text{e}-1)^2n}\right)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you friends

Comment: @Batominovski: $$ S_n = \frac e{e-1}\left(1-\frac1{2n}\frac{e+1}{(e-1)^2}+\frac1{24n^2}\frac{-5e^3+9e^2+57e+11}{(e-1)^4}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right) $$ Not that that makes things any easier.

Comment: @robjohn  I got the same expansion but was too lazy to write the $n^{-2}$-term down.  Unfortunately, I don't know how useful this expansion will be in terms of proving the inequality.  Of course, an inductive proof is out of the question in my opinion.